# Correct syntax to use for scroll events?

Tags: jquery

I have a function named `myFunction` running as soon the window gets scrolled. This one is working fine as expected:

```
$(function () {
  $(window).scroll(myFunction);
  myFunction();
});
```

While this one is not working at all:

```
$(function () {
  $(window).on("scroll", myFunction());
  myFunction();
});
```

I don’t understand, what’s wrong with version 2? Also, why do I have to mention `myFunction()` twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What’s wrong with version 2.

In the second example you are immediately invoking `myFunction()` and setting it's *response* to the event handler. Presumably you don't return a function from this call, so nothing happens.

For clarity, the first example works as you're providing the function *reference* to the event handler.

> Why do I have to mention myFunction() twice?

It's because the you assign `myFunction()` to the event handler, and also to run immediately when the page loads. If you want to remove this duplication you could instead trigger the `scroll` event to happen on load:

```
$(function () {
  $(window).on("scroll", myFunction).trigger('scroll');
});
```

Comment: Nice explanation especially the example with trigger event to avoid code duplication.

Comment: Yes, Rory, I fully agree with gvgvgvijayan: very well explained. Thank you very much.